# Decay of hydrogen nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics, hydrogen, stability, proton-decay

Very naive question. Nuclear decay is associated to more complex nuclei and explained through radiation. What about hydrogen and less complex nuclei? Will these nuclei eventually break apart? Or is it stable for ever?

Comment: And I was referring to stable elements only

Answer (score -1):

Hydrogen atom is the simplest atom in the world. It's just a proton and an electron. His stability is due to the stability of the proton and the electron. As we know the proton and the electron do not decay into smaller particles.

On the other hand the Hydrongen will eventually break apart some time in the far future due to gravitational radiation. But in order a Hydrogen atom to emit enough gravitational energy to split, it needed  $10^{160}$ years.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On a more philosophical note, is 10exp160 years the predicted end of the universe? A time where all sub atomic particles will be floating free in an homogeneous way in space?

Comment: No it is the estimated time of a single atom to decay.

Comment: *"As we know the proton and the electron do not decay into smaller particles. "* Well, many (most) leading candidates for replacing the Standard Model allow proton decay, though the lifetime limit is enormously longer than the current age of the universe. *"On the other hand the Hydrongen will eventually break apart some time in the far future due to gravitational radiation."* No it won't. The egienstates of hydrogen don't radiate gravitational waves for the same reason they don't radiate electromagnetic waves: they are stationary states that exhibit no time variation.